# VallidationSummary não mostra nenhum erro na tela

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou utilizando ValidationSummary nos forms, mas estes não estão sendo renderizados. Existe algum motivo conhecido para este erro?

Exemplo de form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CadastrarPessoaFisica", "Usuario", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <div class="col-md-6 column">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Nome, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Nome" })
        </div><br />

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
            </span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Email, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Email", type = "email" })
        </div><br />

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone">
                </i>
            </span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Telefone, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Telefone" })
        </div><br />

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone">
                </i>
            </span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Celular, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Celular" })
        </div><br />


        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.CPF, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "CPF" })
        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Password, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Senha" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Endereco.CEP, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Cep" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 column">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Endereco.Rua, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Rua" })
        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Endereco.Numero, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Numero" })
        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Endereco.Complemento, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Complemento" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Endereco.Bairro, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Bairro" })
        </div>


        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Endereco.Cidade, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Cidade" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Endereco.Estado, ViewBag.Estado as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="checkbox" /> Eu concordo com os termos
    </div><br />

    <div class="col-md-12 responsive">
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar um exemplo de Form?

Comment: Cigano, atualizei a pergunta. Tentei com true/false no ValidationSummary, mas não obtive êxito...

Comment: Você incluiu no layout os scripts `jquery.validate.js` e  `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`?

Comment: Cigano, o projeto do asp.net por padrão não possui estes scripts. Para conhecimento, eu inicei um projeto WebApi 2... 

Devo adicionar estes scripts?

Comment: Sim, na camada de apresentação, senão não funciona.

Comment: Vou adicionar estes scripts...

Comment: Cigano, sugere algum pacote no nuget especifico para estes scripts? Estou utilizando o bootstrap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possivelmente está faltando o jQuery Unobstrusive Validation. O melhor é usar na sua solução o seguinte pacote NuGet:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive/

Adicione os scripts JS no layout que deve funcionar.