# Mensagem de alerta/pop up em ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Como criar *alert* ou *pop up* para ter o mesmo efeito que o `MessageBox` numa aplicação web?
Meu código

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NovaSolicitacao(Solicitacao pedidoSolicitacao)
{
    pedidoSolicitacao.Usuario_Id = GetUser();
    if (_data.Usuarios.GetByID(GetUser()).Items.Any(x => x.Data == null && x.Status == 1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Você não pode fazer uma nova solicitação pois ainda possui solicitações em aberto!");           
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    ....
}
```

Local funciona dessa forma mas vi que o `MessageBox` não funciona para aplicações web.

Como substituir isso então para aparecer uma janelinha na tela com essa mensagem?

Comment: Cara, vou colocar como comentário porque não sei se ficaria uma boa resposta. Mas pra se fazer pop up aparecer, tem que fazer ele direto na view. Ate onde sei, é na view que faz o uso deles.

Comment: E sabe me dizer como fazer pela view @ÉrikThiago ?

Comment: Voce usa o bootstrap como biblioteca no seu projeto ?

Comment: Uso não @ÉrikThiago ...

Comment: Pode usar o jquery alem da resposta do amigo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PFVitor, boa tarde. Pelo que entendi, você quer um popup que exiba informações.

Você pode utilizar diretamente na view um componente javascript chamado Alert, do seguinte modo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
         alert("Você não pode fazer uma nova solicitação pois ainda possui solicitações em aberto!");
});
</script>
```

O código acima utilizado em uma view irá criar um alerta com a mensagem em parâmetro assim que a página carregar.

Contudo, pelo que estou vendo em seu código, você deseja realizar um tratamento de regra de negócio em seu controller e enviar a mensagem para a view para que esta apresente um erro.

Se este realmente for o cenário, você pode utilizar o componente do mvc ValidationSummary para apresentar os erros na tela que você configurar no controller. Seu código ficaria assim

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NovaSolicitacao(Solicitacao pedidoSolicitacao)
{
    pedidoSolicitacao.Usuario_Id = GetUser();
    if (_data.Usuarios.GetByID(GetUser()).Items.Any(x => x.Data == null && x.Status == 1))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Você não pode fazer uma nova solicitação pois ainda possui solicitações em aberto");     
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    ....
}
```

E então, na view que realiza o submit para o código acima, ficaria:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary
    @*Todo o conteudo do formulario*@
}
```

O Validation summary irá exibir os erros de seu model e aqueles que você adicionar ao Modelstate no Controller.

Caso você tenha criado um projeto Empty, este irá vir sem o Jquery Unobstrusive, responsável por fazer a validação na View. Para adiciona-lo, você pode consultar a seguinte resposta:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31785/4539

Victor, você também pode enviar informações para a view através do dicionario TempData.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NovaSolicitacao(Solicitacao pedidoSolicitacao)
{
    pedidoSolicitacao.Usuario_Id = GetUser();
    if (_data.Usuarios.GetByID(GetUser()).Items.Any(x => x.Data == null && x.Status == 1))
    {
        TempData["mensagemErro"] = "Você não pode fazer uma nova solicitação pois ainda possui solicitações em aberto";     
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    ....
}
```

Na view, você pode exibir como deseja, conforme exemplo abaixo. Neste exemplo, ele verifica se existe uma mensagem de erro, e caso exista, o erro é exibido em uma div de classe field-error.

```
@if(TempData["mensagemErro"] != null)
{
<div class="field-error" >
@TempData["mensagemErro"]
</div>
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54620/discussion-on-answer-by-vinicius-mensagem-de-alerta-pop-up-em-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Usando o TempData é a melhor forma, deu certinho aqui no meu!!